# Is this possible to update a Objective-C library in run time?

Tags: objective-c

Just leave alone the Apple policy, just talking about the Objective-C language only, 
Assume that my programme calling a `.a` library. Is this possible to grep the `.a` from the 
internet, and run a newer version of `.a` instead of old `.a`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not just iOS, but OS X apps (and probably other Unixes in general)

Static libraries (.a files) cannot be replaced while the program is running because they are part of the application binary.  The application binary is mapped into the process's address space.  If you try to change any part of it, you'll almost certainly end up crashing the app.

Dynamic libraries (.so files) are replaceable in theory.  However, most applications load them up once at the beginning or when first needed and then they become part of the application's address space.  I've heard that it is theoretically possible for an application to unload a dynamic library, but I've never seen it done in any real Cooca application.

Answer (score 2):

Not for statically linked libraries (`.a`), at least with any level of sanity. You can certainly do it with dynamically loaded libraries (`.so`); it's one of the normal use cases. Have a look at `dlopen`, `dlclose` and `dlsym` from the dynamic loader (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/MachOReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: You cannot dynamically load downloaded code if you want in on the App Store.

Comment: @AlastairStuart True, but he did say "Just leave alone the Apple policy"

Comment: Missed that, not sure if the sandbox will kill or not also.

Comment: But Objective-C isn't just used for iOS devices.  I write Objective-C on Mac, PC and Linux.